# session-timeout not working for some links in Struts

Tags: java, jsp, session-timeout, struts-1

My application is using **Struts 1** and I have configured 60 as the session timeout in my web.xml. I am using Frames and the left side of my view having the menu tree(links) remains same through out and the right side shows the corresponding pages on click. On timeout majority of the links are displaying the login page. But few are not,they are still in the same flow. Please find the configuration and jsp snippets below for the links which are not timing out.

**web.xml**

```html
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>default</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/do/login</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

**What Not Working**

***struts-config.xml***

```html
<action path="/Report" scope="request" name="form.Report" type="com.mypack.ReportAction" input="/Data.jsp">
  <forward name="show" path="/Data.jsp" />
</action>
```

***menu.jsp***

```html
<tr>
  <td height="24"><b><font size="2">
      <html:link forward="/Report" target="main">Reports</html:link></font></b>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Session timout is not related to struts but to your web application container.  To be sure that every link is redirected to login page when session is dead, you could add a filter in your web.xml and this filter will check the request,  if timout is reached then it redirects it to login page,  otherwide it let it carry on.

Comment: My current web.xml is not using any filters and session timeout is still working for most of the links. I dont understand that aspect of it. And the only mapping to login.jsp in web.xml is added to my question above.

Comment: What i mean, is that you have to add filter even if you have login configured. It's more secure to pass by filter. May be struts could bypass login configuration !

Comment: As @IBJ said create a filter, filter is invoked before your `action  class` corresponding to the requested url. In `filter` you check for the `session`, if `session` is not available you can redirect your to `login page`. [Find the Example code for session filter](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-session-handling-tutorial-using-servlet-filters-session-error-filter-servlet-filter/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter as below:

add lines below to your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.rbz.SessionFilter
    </filter-class>    
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then in your sources, add class below

```
package com.rbz;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class SessionFilter implements Filter {


    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;    

    // try to get session
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    String url = request.getServletPath();

    if ((null != session && !session.isNew()) || (null == session && url.contains("login.jsp")) {     
      chain.doFilter(req, res);          
    } else {          
      response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }   


    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

This code is not tested !